# W Register in Assembly Not defined? - Microchip pic16f84a

Tags: assembly, pic

I am using this instruction:

```
DEC COUNT
MOVF COUNT,w
BSF PORTB,w
```

i am getting the following error:
`Symbol not previously defined (W)` in w i ment of course the register w.

Comment: Clarify what CPU you are targeting.

Comment: Ah yes , my bad , Microchip pic16f84a @OndrejTucny

Comment: What IDE you are using!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problematic instruction is

```
BSF PORTB, w
```

`BSF` takes a bit number, not a register - interestingly enough, when switching to a capital `W` it goes through the assembler, but most likely generates other code than intended. Use something like

```
BSF PORTB, 2      ; set bit number 2 (0b00000100)
```

instead. If you need to calculate the bit number, you have to do it manually, e.g. through a rotate instruction, something like this:

```
    ...
    MOVLW   0b00000001  ; bit 0
    MOVWF   COUNT

Loop:
    MOVFW   COUNT       ; COUNT => W
    MOVWF   PORTB       ; COUNT => PORTB (8 bits!)

    BCF     STATUS, C   ; clear carry
    RLF     COUNT, F    ; shift left COUNT

    BTFSS   STATUS, C   ; eight bits rotated?
    GOTO    Loop        ; no, continue

    ...
```

Comment: ah ok, i thought i can use a variable to ease my work, looks like i will have to do it manually, anyways i appreciate your help, cheers!